# How to replace infinites in calculating mean of a column using R

Tags: r, dataframe

This might be easy but I have not found a solution yet - I have a big data frame with several columns and rows. At some point in my code, I have to calculate the mean of a column as below:

df:

```
col1  col2  col3
A      2      2
B      5     inf
C      4      3
```

```
df$col3_mean <- mean(df$col3)
```

The code above gives me `inf` as a result of mean of the col3 - but what I want to do is that before calculating the mean, if there is `inf` in the column, replace it with the value of the col2 (which in my example inf should be replaced by 5 and then mean should be calculated) then calculate the mean.

So the mean should be the mean of `(2+5+3)/3` for the col3.

I have not been able to write a code for this since I am not an expert in R - it would be great if you give some help on this. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `ifelse()` inside `mean()` to use elements of `col2` if the corresponding elements of `col3` are `Inf`:

```
> mean(ifelse(df$col3 == Inf, df$col2, df$col3))
[1] 3.333333
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just replace the infinite values in column `c3` by setting them to the values of `c2`:

```
df$col3[is.infinite(df$col3)] = df$col2[is.infinite(df$col3)]
```

This will replace the  `Inf` values permanently, however. If you just want to replace them while computing the mean, you will have to replace them temporary in the function call:

```
mean(c(df$col3[!is.inifinite(df$col3)],df$col2[is.infinite(df$col3)])
```

So, your data remains untampered but you get the mean you want.